# Check if multple variables greater than zero in python

Tags: python

```
A = 200
B = -140
C = 400
D = -260

if A < 0:
   v1 = 0
else:
   v1 = A

if B < 0:
   v2 = 0
else:
   v2 = B

 if C < 0:
   v3 = 0
else:
   v3 = C

if D < 0:
   v4 = 0
else:
   v4 = C
```

What is the shorthand implementation for the above code structure.? 
Is there a better / elegant / convenient way to do this?

Comment: It's worth noting that ``CapWords`` is generally reserved for classes in Python - check [the Python style guide (PEP-8)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the python community would advise against obscure variable names like `A,B,C,D` anyway :^).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
A = 200
B = -140
C = 400
D = -260

v1, v2, v3, v4 = [x if x > 0 else 0 for x in (A, B, C, D)]
```

If you prefer to use the `max` function to the python ternary operator, it would look like:

```
v1, v2, v3, v4 = [max(x, 0) for x in (A, B, C, D)]
```

However, if you're planning on having all of these variables treated the same, you might want to consider putting them in a list/tuple in the first place.

```
values = [200, -140, 400, -260]
values = [max(x, 0) for x in values]
```

Comment: +1 Prefer this to using `map` and `lambda` to accomplish something a list comprehension does just fine.

Answer (score 4):

This can be solved easily by using [the `max()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#max) and unpacking a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY&list=UUAuqj5Bs5mTTl1mIVDmuAlw&index=1&feature=plcp).

```
v1, v2, v3, v4 = [max(x, 0) for x in [a, b, c, d]]
```

An alternative solution is to use the `map()` function - this is, however, less readable:

```
v1, v2, v3, v4 = map(lambda x: max(x,0), [a, b, c, d])
```

Comment: `(max(x, 0) for x in [A, B, C, D])` is far more readable IMHO.

Comment: @mgilson I agree - and made the change in my edit, along with some explanation and links.

Answer (score 2):

Sanity check with `min()` and `max()`.

```
v1 = max(0, A)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [mgilson's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12567333/455276), you could subclass `int` into a custom class to achieve this

```
>>> class V(int):
...    def __new__(cls,val,**kwargs):
...       return super(V,cls).__new__(cls,max(val,0))
```

Then use it directly:

```
>>> A=V(200)
200
>>> B=V(-140)
0
>>> [V(i) for i in [200, -140, 400, -260]]
[200, 0, 400, 0]     
>>> A,B,C,D = [V(i) for i in [200, -140, 400, -260]]
```

The only advantage to do it this way is you can then override `__sub__` and `__add__` `__mul__` appropriately and then you V ints will *always* greater than 0 even if you have `a=V(50)-100`

Example:

```
>>> class V(int):
...    def __new__(cls,val,**kwargs):
...       return super(V,cls).__new__(cls,max(val,0)) 
...    def __sub__(self,other):
...       if int.__sub__(self,other)<0:
...         return 0
...       else:
...         return int.__sub__(self,other) 
>>> a=V(50)
>>> b=V(100)
>>> a-b                #ordinarily 50-100 would be -50, no?
0
```